# Blender And Vuforia

Tags: android, augmented-reality, blender, qcar-sdk

Is there a way to open the Vuforia AR sample packages in blender. I know Vuforia AR has a sdk for Unity 3d, but I am currently using Blender and don't wanna drop $400 to just get the Android license for Unity. Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather late on this one, but I have just written a parser of Wavefront OBJ files to Vuforia's format - the other way round to what thechrisberry wants. Credit to [stackoverflow doyen rodrigo-silveira](http://rodrigo-silveira.com/opengl-tutorial-parsing-obj-file-blender) for giving the initiating idea.

The Vuforia samples have basically simple object models - cubes and teapots - so it shouldn't be difficult to make an OBJ file out of them and import this to Blender. You would just have to convert the vertices, normals, texCoords and indices arrays of Vuforia's samples to the OBJ text format (v, vn, vt and f elements), and include the PNG texture file from the sample.

Answer (score 2):

Blender is a 3D modeling software and Unity 3D is a game engine. They are totally different and are made for different purposes. If you want to tweak the sample apps with your own customization, I would recommend using Vuforia SDK for Android. But that includes coding as opposed to Unity which is just drag and drop for simple apps.

Comment: Well blender does provide a game engine http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/game-engine I don't know if its comparable to Unity.

Comment: Of course it supports creating game somehow but the main purpose of Blender is modeling and animation.

Comment: True I agree that is its intent, I guess what I want to do is create a 3d square in blender and get that square into Vuforia. It not clear cut.

Comment: I did [something](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chsHh0pEhzw) similar but not with unity. But if you want, I can give you an Activation code for unity version 3.x.

Comment: that demo is awesome. Let me ask you this what would you suggest to use with vuforia?

Comment: I used jPCT with Vuforia. But that's all programming. Also creating 3D models and animation which jPCT can handle, is little tricky. You can use any rendering engine (not game engine) which supports Android to create similar stuff. But again, that's not a trivial task. If you want something quick and easy, I think Unity is your best choice.

Comment: I will give Unity a try. Thanks for the info, super helpful.